# Library/Caches behavior prior to iOS 5

Tags: ios, caching

Does the OS purge the "Caches" directory prior to iOS 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, prior to iOS 5.0, the default behaviour was:

- Documents folder - backed up to iTunes
- Caches folder - not backed up

Neither folder was purged by the OS. The Apple docs from v4.3 state:

**Caches**

*Contains cached data that can be regenerated as needed. Applications should never rely on the existence of cache files. Cache files should be placed in a directory whose name matches the bundle identifier of the application.
By convention, applications should store cache files in a subdirectory whose name matches the bundle identifier of the application. For example, if your application is named MyApp and has the bundle identifier com.example.MyApp, you would put user-specific cache files in the ~/Library/Caches/com.example.MyApp/ directory.*

This is from June 2011 so sounds like it was in preparation for iOS 5.0.

Comment: You can download docs for iOS 4.1 - 4.3 within Xcode preferences, under the Documentation tab. They're then available in the Organizer.